# How to send GET and POST requests in one session?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I send `GET` request and parse response to set `VIEWSTATE` and `EVENTVALIDATION` .
Then I send `POST` request with parameters, but variables are invalid!
So, how to send `GET` and `POST` requests in one session? Page is here http://www.aogc2.state.ar.us:8080/DWClient/Login.aspx

Here is my code

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
                .build();
private String sendGet() throws IOException {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url+"Login.aspx");
        httpget.addHeader("User-Agent",USER_AGENT);
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget)) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
            StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                result.append(line);
            }
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            updateViewState(result.toString());
            return result.toString();
        }
    }

    private String sendPost() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        HttpRequest login = RequestBuilder.post()
                .setUri(new URI(url+"Login.aspx"))
                .addParameter("DWC$DWMessages", "")
                .addParameter("__VIEWSTATE", viewState)
                .addParameter("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation)
                .addParameter("DWC_NotificationToolTip_ClientState", "")
                .addParameter("LoginWebPart$LoginTypes", "Guest")
                .addParameter("LoginWebPart$TextBoxUserName", "")
                .addParameter("LoginWebPart$TextBoxPassword", "")
                .addParameter("LoginWebPart$ButtonLogin", "Login")
                .addParameter("LoginWebPart_LanguageContextMenu_ClientState", "")
                .addHeader("User-Agent",USER_AGENT)
                .build();
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute((HttpUriRequest)login)) {
            HttpEntity entity = response2.getEntity();
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
            StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                result.append(line);
            }
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            return result.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In one HTTP session on the server you mean I think?

Comment: Where do you parse the response? Where do you set the variables? What exactly do you mean by "but variables are invalid"?

Comment: Yes. the server assigns your subsession after connected. So, my code connects twice and subSessions and variables is different.

Comment: But how does the server do it? With a cookie?

Comment: I set variables in method updateViewState() it's easy Jsoup.parse(result)  .

Comment: variables are invalid, It means that variables change after each connections

Comment: No, I think.  Cookies are the same after each connections :). So server assings you cookie (DWSession, and others) one time. I saw it in browser.

Comment: Please, somebody help

Comment: So, when I do this: setUri(url+"Login.aspx"+subSession)   I get Error An error has occurred (fd86da73-9c07-4304-9c4e-bd0124031586_1). Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.